# Android:Remove bottom of elevation margin

Tags: android, elevation, cardview

I use this code for add elevation to layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:contentPadding="0dp"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp">
```

But bottom of elevation add margin and i can not remove margin bottom

Image: [image]

Comment: try: `card_view:contentPadding="-8dp"`...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 Not working

Comment: can you please post an image of your current view and expected output?

Comment: @FerdousAhamed added to question

Answer (score 0):

`CardView` adds padding in platforms pre-5.0 to draw shadows. In Lolipop and up, your should not set `useCompatPadding=true`, if you don't want any gap.

Comment: In my code have app:cardUseCompatPadding="true", but not work

Comment: you should remove it

Comment: not working. in pre lililop marginBottm="-7dp" not work but >lililop work

Comment: add android:padding="0dp"